# How to use .innerHTML in template element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an app with a framework that uses templates in HTML pretty heavily. It was all going well until I bumped into this problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this has to do with my code itself using templates and JavaScipt not being able to read the inside of that template.

Here's a minature version of my code which I am experiencing errors with.

**HTML**

```
<template id="main.html">
     <p id="paragraph">This text needs to be changed in 
     JS</p>
     <button onclick=example()>Click ME!</button>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function example (){
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "This text has been changed!"}
```

**Error:**

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' 
 of null
```

Is there any way of avoiding this error?

Comment: Be wary of using elements with id *within* a template. If multiple elements are created from the template you will end up with duplicate ids, which is **bad**. You will need to update/delete the id attribute from created elements. Either that or use class names or data attributes as your hook to get the elements in the  template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Template-element content is not rendered by default**

You can re-use the content in a template-element as many times as you want, but you need to manually specify that using Javascript. If you don't use any Javascript to render your template-element it won't be visible in the DOM. Resulting in your code not finding the paragraph (which is in the template-element).

**2) Make sure you call your Javascript after the DOM is loaded**

A web-page gets loaded from top to bottom. If you don't place your Javascript-code on the bottom of your body tag, or manually say it needs to be loaded after the DOM is ready, your code tries to find an element before that element even exists.

**3) Your code has small mistakes like missing paragraphs etc.**

Fix that using a good editor.

This example code shows you how it can be done:

**Javascript:**

```
function example() {
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "This text has been changed!";
}


function init() {
    //Get the template-element by id
    let mainTemplate = document.getElementById("main");
    //Create a new div-element to hold template content
    let parent = document.createElement("div");

    //IMPORTANT!
    //Cloning template content into HTML DOM so it's visible.
    //This part - content.cloneNode - makes your template content visible after being appended to the body, or another legal element in the DOM.
    parent.append(mainTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));

    //Append to body
    document.body.append(parent);
}   

//After dom is ready: Launch init function
document.onload = init();
```

**HTML:**

```
<template id="main">
     <p id="paragraph">This text needs to be changed in 
     JS</p>
     <button onclick="example()">Click ME!</button>
</template>
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovc1mrs2/

You probably want to append the content of your template directly to the body, or to another element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you just forgot to put "()" after "function example."

```js
 function example() {
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "This text has been changed!"}
```

```html
         <p id="paragraph">This text needs to be changed in 
         JS</p>
         <button onclick=example()>Click ME!</button>
```

Comment: No. Add template-tags around your HTML and you'll see that your code snippet won't work. This question is specifically about template-tags.

Comment: Always better to add a condition to prevent the null/undefined error:
e.g.

function example() {
if(document.getElementById("paragraph")){
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "This text has been changed!"
}
}

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, sadly, I edited it in the post, sadly, this is not the problem I had...

Comment: @O'Niel Yes, your response answered my question, thank you! I marked your response as the answer for this thread.

Answer (score -1):

add "()" after example in js.

**Updated Javascript code :**

`function example () {
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "This text has been changed!"
};`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I edited my response to include the parenthesis. But that's not the problem I am experiencing